# Automate the OOBE setup steps for Windows 10

Tags: automation, sysprep, imaging, vmware-fusion, windows-10

I am not sure if this is possible. I have been reading a bit about answer files but that seems to be more for the actual installation of windows to me.

This is the process we currently use:

- Install windows
- Go into audit mode
- Install required software / windows updates
- Sysprep image when finished and shutdown machine
- Capture image
- Restore image to client machines

The whole process works fine but I would like to be able to reduce the amount of clicks needed after restoring the image.

Is there a way to automate the initial windows 10 settings such as accepting the EULA, changing the privacy settings, added a local user, possibly even joining a domain.  After the computer has been reimaged we currently do this manually.

To make matters a bit harder our clients are Macs and Windows runs in VMware Fusion so the Sysprep'ed Windows comes on the Mac as part of the overall Mac image.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but it gets the job done:

1. Start with Vanilla Win 10 image running in audit mode, load apps. Sysprep OOBE.
2. Once shutdown use WINPE Boot flash thumb drive to copy wimimage to MDT server using DISM.
3. Import WIM and followed this lab the TECHNET guys wrote: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt297534(v=vs.85).aspx.

Might need to tweak for your environment but 90% of the hard work completed by them.

Cheers